# Images loading after $(window).on('load', function()

Tags: jquery

We have some jQuery that is designed to resize the images according to the width of the window (and another function to resize them again if the user changes the window size)

Originally this worked with $(document).ready(function() but after some updates it failed to work - the images were being loaded too late and they all returned dimensions of 0px

After updating the function to $(window).on('load', function () it worked - but it would appear there was a caveat.

Images are loaded from a DB. If they are not available, stock default images are loaded. These are held locally in an images directory. Both work when running the application in debug (or Start without debugging in VS), but the local images are returning dimensions of 0px from the live site. For some reason it would appear they are being loaded too late - I would have thought the opposite and a call to a DB would be longer.

This is how the images are called

```
Function LoadImages() As ActionResult
        Try
            SetHOAID()
            Dim vPath As String = Url.Content("~/")
            Dim appPath As String = ""
            appPath = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Url.Host, If(HttpContext.Request.Url.Port = 80, String.Empty, ":" & HttpContext.Request.Url.Port), HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath)
            If Not appPath.Contains("localhost") Then
                appPath += "/"
            End If

            Dim ThemeID As Integer = 0
            Dim SB As New StringBuilder
            SB.Append("<div id=""imageHeader"" class=""row"" style=""padding-top:   30px; padding-left: 30px; "">")
            SB.AppendLine()
            If CheckTable("HOA3_Themes", Session("HOAID")) = True Then
                Dim vYear As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Today)
                strSQL = "SELECT Theme_ID, CAST(STRING('" & vYear & "-', RIGHT(Theme_Start, 2), '-', LEFT(Theme_Start, 2))AS date) AS StartDate, "
                strSQL += "Theme_ID, CAST(STRING('" & vYear & "-', RIGHT(Theme_End, 2), '-', LEFT(Theme_End, 2))AS date) AS EndDate "
                strSQL += "FROM HOA3_Themes "
                strSQL += "WHERE StartDate <= CURRENT DATE AND EndDate >= CURRENT DATE "
                Using DS As DataSet = ReturnDataSet_Data(strSQL, Session("HOAID"), False)
                    If DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        'No current theme, try and get the default

                        strSQL = "SELECT Theme_ID FROM HOA3_Themes WHERE Theme_Default = 1 AND Theme_Live = 1"
                        ThemeID = ReturnScalarInteger_Data(strSQL, Session("HOAID"), False)
                    Else
                        For Each row In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                            ThemeID = row("Theme_ID")
                        Next

                    End If
                End Using

                If Not ThemeID = 0 Then
                    strSQL = "SELECT Image_ID FROM HOA3_Theme_Images WHERE Theme_ID = " & ThemeID
                    Using DS As DataSet = ReturnDataSet_Data(strSQL, Session("HOAID"), False)
                        If DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count < 5 Then
                            'Load the default images
                        Else
                            Dim i As Integer = 1
                            For Each Row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows

                                strSQL = "SELECT Image_Name, Image_Description FROM HOA3_Images WHERE Image_ID = " & Row("Image_ID")
                                Dim vName As String = ""
                                Dim vDesc As String = ""
                                Using DS2 As DataSet = ReturnDataSet_Data(strSQL, Session("HOAID"), True)
                                    For Each SubRow As DataRow In DS2.Tables(0).Rows
                                        vName = ReturnText(SubRow("Image_Name"))
                                        vDesc = ReturnText(SubRow("Image_Description"))
                                    Next
                                End Using
                                SB.Append("<div class=""img-shadow"" >")
                                SB.AppendLine()
                                SB.Append("<img id=""TopImage_" & i & """ title=""" & vName & """ alt=""" & vDesc & """ src=""" & appPath & "Secure/ImageViewer/Index/" & Row("Image_ID") & "/Thumbnail"" style=""height: 140px""/>")
                                SB.AppendLine()

                                SB.Append("</div>")
                                SB.AppendLine()
                                i += 1
                            Next
                        End If

                    End Using

                Else
                    'Load the default images
                    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
                        SB.Append("<div class=""img-shadow"" >")
                        SB.AppendLine()
                        SB.Append("<img id=""TopImage_" & i & """ title=""Image_" & i & """ alt=""Image_" & i & """ src=""" & appPath & "Images/Default/HOA_00" & i & ".jpg"" style=""height: 140px""/>")
                        SB.AppendLine()

                        SB.Append("</div>")
                        SB.AppendLine()
                    Next

                End If


            Else
                'Load the default images
                For i As Integer = 1 To 5
                    SB.Append("<div class=""img-shadow"" >")
                    SB.AppendLine()
                    SB.Append("<img id=""TopImage_" & i & """ title=""Image_" & i & """ alt=""Image_" & i & """ src=""" & appPath & "Images/Default/HOA_00" & i & ".jpg"" style=""height: 140px""/>")
                    SB.AppendLine()

                    SB.Append("</div>")
                    SB.AppendLine()
                Next

            End If






            SB.Append("</div>")
            Return Content(SB.ToString)

        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex, 187, PageName)
            Return Content("<p> Error </p>")
        End Try
    End Function
```

This is the script that resizes them

```
<script>
    //Set image widths
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('load',function () {

        // $('img').on('load', function () {
        // var divWidth = $(window).width();
        var divWidth;
        if (Modernizr.mq('(divWidth: 0px)')) {
            divWidth = function (width) {
                return Modernizr.mq('(divWidth: ' + width + 'px)');

            };
        }
        else {
            divWidth = $(window).width();
        }

        if (divWidth <= 900) {
            // alert('1 Mobile Width is ' + divWidth);
            $("#TopImagesDiv").css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            //alert('1 Full Width is ' + divWidth);
            $("#TopImagesDiv").css("display", "block");
        }

        var imagePadding = 175;
        var imageOneWidth = $('#TopImage_1').width();
        var imageTwoWidth = $('#TopImage_2').width();
        var imageThreeWidth = $('#TopImage_3').width();
        var imageFourWidth = $('#TopImage_4').width();
        var imageFiveWidth = $('#TopImage_5').width();
        var totalImageWidth = parseInt(imagePadding + imageOneWidth + imageTwoWidth + imageThreeWidth + imageFourWidth + imageFiveWidth);
        var widthDifference = divWidth - totalImageWidth;
        var percentDifference = Math.round(widthDifference / divWidth * 100);

        var imageOneHeight = $('#TopImage_1').height();
        var imageTwoHeight = $('#TopImage_2').height();
        var imageThreeHeight = $('#TopImage_3').height();
        var imageFourHeight = $('#TopImage_4').height();
        var imageFiveHeight = $('#TopImage_5').height();

        var imageOneWidth = $('#TopImage_1').width();
        var imageTwoWidth = $('#TopImage_2').width();
        var imageThreeWidth = $('#TopImage_3').width();
        var imageFourWidth = $('#TopImage_4').width();
        var imageFiveWidth = $('#TopImage_5').width();

        $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(imageOneHeight + (imageOneHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(imageTwoHeight + (imageTwoHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(imageThreeHeight + (imageThreeHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(imageFourHeight + (imageFourHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(imageFiveHeight + (imageFiveHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");

        $('#TopImage_1').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageOneWidth + (imageOneWidth / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_2').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageTwoWidth + (imageTwoWidth / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_3').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageThreeWidth + (imageThreeWidth / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_4').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFourWidth + (imageFourWidth / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
        $('#TopImage_5').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFiveWidth + (imageFiveWidth / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");

       
    })
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

=========== EDIT ADDED =============

If I check the element (one of five) from the site, I get this for the one returned from the DB

```
<img id="TopImage_1" title="Entrance" alt="Entrance" src="http://DomainName.org/HOA5/Secure/ImageViewer/Index/664/Thumbnail" style="height: 55px; width: 129px;">
```

644 is the ID number and Thumbnail is the image size for that description. This works as intended.

If I check the element where there are no DB images and it defaults to the local directory it does this

```
<img id="TopImage_1" title="Image_1" alt="Image_1" src="http://DomainName.com/HOA5/Images/Default/HOA_001.jpg" style="height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

This one is the problem child

Comment: Is there other code involved in setting image src or are they already embedded in page with hard coded src paths? A [mre] that demonstrates the issue would help

Comment: CharlieFL - the code for returning the images is the first example above. The image, name and description are returned from the DB and a default height of 140px is set to them

Comment: That db code doesn't tell us that the images are in the html with src set when page loads though. For example that html could be injected asynchronously. Just trying to narrow down possibilities is all

Comment: I have added some more to the question

Comment: Check in browser dev tools network if image is even loading and dimensions shown there

Comment: Interestingly, if I maximise the browser and refresh some images do appear, but they are small and squashed. Original image is 550x349 but loaded image is 165x36, so the ratio has changed from 1.57 to 0.22. The ratio should be the same

Comment: You really need to provide a runnable [mcve] as it's really hard to guess without being able to use browser tools to help debug it. For all we know the parent elements are hidden. Lots and lots of possibilities here

Comment: I'll do an Arnie and be back! Thank you for taking the time to reply :-) - The parent elements are not being hidden, the images are being reset to a different ratio and only visible when the browser is taking up a large chunk of screen. The DB ones work. I've probably done something silly and just can't see it

Answer (score 0):

What I always do, is that I add an array at the top of the code:

```
<script>var afterJQ = [];</script>
```

at the end of the page I run what ever function is in that array:

```
<script>for(var i=0; i< afterJQ.length;i++) afterJQ[i]();</script>
```

now where ever I need something to run after jQuery, I just push it as a function in `afterJQ`:

```
afterJQ.push(function(){
     //code here will run after jQuery is loaded

});
```

```html
<script>var afterJQ = [];</script>


<div>Lots of things here</div>
<div id="fill-after"></div>

<script>
afterJQ.push(function(){
    $('#fill-after').html('jQuery is loaded');

});
</script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>for(var i=0; i< afterJQ.length;i++) afterJQ[i]();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function in jQuery. It might help you out in your case.

Comment: Bimal. The problem is determining the original image type (landscape or portrait) then getting them all to the same height and fitting the page width

Comment: @gchq if the idea is to get the same height and width to all images then go for a image which  is a valid image i.e. has width and height. Next, calculate the desired width and height once and then apply it to all images. Css property object-fit can also help you out for getting proper image.

Comment: Bimal - the idea is to get them all to the same height. The width will vary, but should always retain the same ratio, so that different image types (and the customer could save anything) will adjust to the width of the page. The script works for DB images, and for both local and DB images when debugging - just the live site where it falls over with local ones

Comment: @gchq Might be a read permission issue on the image folder. If you are on a linux server then you can use chmod command.

Comment: Bimal - not that. If I go to the page and click 'inspect' - then drill down to the image link and hover over it the Image displays in the box above. Plus, as mentioned above, when the page is maximised and refreshed the images are being displayed, but out of proportion and very small. Server is Windows 2019 running IIS

Comment: @gchq in that case something might be going wrong during your calculation. You can debug the code with console.log statement and trace the issue to the problematic elements.

Comment: Bimal - console log is not returning any errors or warnings. As the calculations work for DB images it would be odd if they didn't for a static image

Comment: @gchq Can you share with me a link to the live page ?

Comment: Bimal - I have found a few issues with the maths in the code - some image sizes work but others don't. I'm reworking that once the brain fog clears. Thank you for hanging in with me :-)

Comment: Got it working - there were two issues, so I will post what I found as an answer - may help others

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were two separate issues.

This was how the images were being displayed

[image]

After changing the maths in the jQuery the image widths were correct and also adjusting correctly, but...

[image]

I then noticed that when then images the style only included height. Setting the width to auto fixed that, now it looks like this

[image]

Changing the script to below means that images (of any size or ratio) now adjust to the screen size and readjust if that changes. If the screen size is very small it removes the images

```
<script>
    //Set image widths
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('load',function () {

        // $('img').on('load', function () {
        // var divWidth = $(window).width();
        var divWidth;
        if (Modernizr.mq('(divWidth: 0px)')) {
            divWidth = function (width) {
                return Modernizr.mq('(divWidth: ' + width + 'px)');

            };
        }
        else {
            divWidth = $(window).width();
        }

        if (divWidth <= 900) {
            // alert('1 Mobile Width is ' + divWidth);
            $("#TopImagesDiv").css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            //alert('1 Full Width is ' + divWidth);
            $("#TopImagesDiv").css("display", "block");
        }

        //Default the image array loaded is smaller than the window width
        var isLarger = false;


        var imagePadding = 175;
        divWidth = (divWidth - imagePadding); //Overall available width for images
        var imageOneWidth = $('#TopImage_1').width();
        var imageTwoWidth = $('#TopImage_2').width();
        var imageThreeWidth = $('#TopImage_3').width();
        var imageFourWidth = $('#TopImage_4').width();
        var imageFiveWidth = $('#TopImage_5').width();
        var totalImageWidth = parseInt(imageOneWidth + imageTwoWidth + imageThreeWidth + imageFourWidth + imageFiveWidth);
        
        var widthDifference = divWidth - totalImageWidth;
      
        var percentDifference;
        if (totalImageWidth > divWidth) { // The image array loaded is larger than the window width
            widthDifference = totalImageWidth - divWidth;
            isLarger = true;
           
            percentDifference = Math.round(divWidth / totalImageWidth * 100);
            //Difference is the wrong way round
            percentDifference = (100 - percentDifference);
        }
        else {
            percentDifference = Math.round(totalImageWidth / divWidth * 100);
            percentDifference = (100 - percentDifference);
        }
        

        var imageOneHeight = $('#TopImage_1').height();
        var imageTwoHeight = $('#TopImage_2').height();
        var imageThreeHeight = $('#TopImage_3').height();
        var imageFourHeight = $('#TopImage_4').height();
        var imageFiveHeight = $('#TopImage_5').height();

        if (isLarger == false) {
            $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(imageOneHeight + (imageOneHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(imageTwoHeight + (imageTwoHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(imageThreeHeight + (imageThreeHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(imageFourHeight + (imageFourHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(imageFiveHeight + (imageFiveHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");

            $('#TopImage_1').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageOneWidth + (imageOneWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageTwoWidth + (imageTwoWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageThreeWidth + (imageThreeWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFourWidth + (imageFourWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFiveWidth + (imageFiveWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
        }

        else {
            $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(imageOneHeight - (imageOneHeight * percentDifference / 100 )) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(imageTwoHeight - (imageTwoHeight * percentDifference / 100 )) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(imageThreeHeight - (imageThreeHeight * percentDifference / 100 )) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(imageFourHeight - (imageFourHeight * percentDifference / 100 )) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(imageFiveHeight - (imageFiveHeight * percentDifference / 100 )) + "px");

            $('#TopImage_1').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageOneWidth - (imageOneWidth * percentDifference / 100 ))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageTwoWidth - (imageTwoWidth * percentDifference / 100 ))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageThreeWidth - (imageThreeWidth * percentDifference / 100 ))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFourWidth - (imageFourWidth * percentDifference / 100 ))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFiveWidth - (imageFiveWidth * percentDifference / 100 ))) + "px");

        }

       
    })
</script>

<script>
    //Resize images
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function () {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };


    var vDebounce = debounce(function () {
        var divWidth;
        if (Modernizr.mq('(divWidth: 0px)')) {
            divWidth = function (width) {
                return Modernizr.mq('(divWidth: ' + width + 'px)');

            };
        }
        else {
            divWidth = $(window).width();
        }

        if (divWidth <= 900) {
            //alert('2 Mobile Width is ' + divWidth);
            $("#TopImagesDiv").css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            // alert('2 Full Width is ' + divWidth);
            $("#TopImagesDiv").css("display", "block");
        }

        //Default the image array loaded is smaller than the window width
        var isLarger = false;


        //alert(divWidth);
        var imagePadding = 175;
        divWidth = (divWidth - imagePadding); //Overall available width for images
        var imageOneWidth = $('#TopImage_1').width();
        var imageTwoWidth = $('#TopImage_2').width();
        var imageThreeWidth = $('#TopImage_3').width();
        var imageFourWidth = $('#TopImage_4').width();
        var imageFiveWidth = $('#TopImage_5').width();
        var totalImageWidth = parseInt(imageOneWidth + imageTwoWidth + imageThreeWidth + imageFourWidth + imageFiveWidth);

        var widthDifference = divWidth - totalImageWidth;
       
        var percentDifference;
        if (totalImageWidth > divWidth) { // The image array loaded is larger than the window width
            widthDifference = totalImageWidth - divWidth;
            isLarger = true;
           
            percentDifference = Math.round(divWidth / totalImageWidth * 100);
            //Difference is the wrong way round
            percentDifference = (100 - percentDifference);
        }
        else {
            percentDifference = Math.round(totalImageWidth / divWidth * 100);
            percentDifference = (100 - percentDifference);
        }
        

        var imageOneHeight = $('#TopImage_1').height();
        var imageTwoHeight = $('#TopImage_2').height();
        var imageThreeHeight = $('#TopImage_3').height();
        var imageFourHeight = $('#TopImage_4').height();
        var imageFiveHeight = $('#TopImage_5').height();

        if (isLarger == false) {
            $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(imageOneHeight + (imageOneHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(imageTwoHeight + (imageTwoHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(imageThreeHeight + (imageThreeHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(imageFourHeight + (imageFourHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(imageFiveHeight + (imageFiveHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");

            $('#TopImage_1').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageOneWidth + (imageOneWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageTwoWidth + (imageTwoWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageThreeWidth + (imageThreeWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFourWidth + (imageFourWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFiveWidth + (imageFiveWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
        }

        else {
            $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(imageOneHeight - (imageOneHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(imageTwoHeight - (imageTwoHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(imageThreeHeight - (imageThreeHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(imageFourHeight - (imageFourHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(imageFiveHeight - (imageFiveHeight * percentDifference / 100)) + "px");

            $('#TopImage_1').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageOneWidth - (imageOneWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_2').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageTwoWidth - (imageTwoWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_3').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageThreeWidth - (imageThreeWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_4').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFourWidth - (imageFourWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");
            $('#TopImage_5').css('width', Math.round(parseInt(imageFiveWidth - (imageFiveWidth * percentDifference / 100))) + "px");

        }

       
    }, 250);

    $(window).on('resize', vDebounce);
</script>
```